# How to configure RDF on fields?

Tags: 8

I have a type of recipe content and I would like google to display additional information in its results.

There is a built-in module to Drupal 8 "RDF" but I can not find anything to configure it on my fields.

How does it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drupal built in RDF module works automatically and cannot be directly influenced from the user interface. There is however the [Schema.org configuration tool (RDF UI)](https://www.drupal.org/project/rdfui) module.

> The module enables you to specify mappings between content types and
>   fields with types and properties of Schema.org and build Content types
>   based on schema.org. Through the rdf module, specified mappings will
>   be embedded in HTML as RDFa, to provide semantically rich data.

The video on the module page explains the process quite well.

Comment: I applied schema.org with RDFUI on my recipe content type, but I do not see them on google testing structured data
 https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.s1biose.com%2Frecette%2Fmini-brochettes-de-jambon-melon-fromage

Comment: Google fetches the pages as an anonymous user. Have you cleared the Drupal cache?

Comment: Ps. It is better to accept an answer after you have verified it works. Other people are less likely to respond to an answered question :)

Comment: OK. The module works and when I inspect my page, schema.org is applied. But there is no result on the google tools (see link above). An idea ?

Comment: @ZenImagine The fields are mapped, but I see no references to the Recipe type. Without a 'parent' item those fields have no meaning. Are you sure the node is configured as a recipe type?

Comment: Yes the recipes are correctly configured. Here are screenshots of my configuration https://www.drupal.org/node/2895379

Comment: @ZenImagine Not sure, but there are other reported issues about the module not working. Did you try https://www.drupal.org/node/2893779 already? It is probably a bug (meaning that there is unfortunately nothing more we can do here).

Comment: Thank you but the patch does not work for me